# How to Append Text to File (with Powershell)

Tags: powershell, code-generation

I am new to PowerShell, and am having trouble getting it to "echo" some variables back to a generated '.ps1' file. The use case is that I am attempting to make a script generator for media conversion that will generate another re-useable script once you enter all the required information.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
# Initialize
$TRACK_COUNTER=0

$artist=Read-Host -Prompt "Artist/Band Name"
$language=Read-Host -Prompt "Language (use ISO 639-2 codes)" 
$album_or_single=Read-Host -Prompt "Is this an Album/Sound-Track or a collection of Singles (0 for album/sound-track, 1 for single's)" 

# Album
if ($album_or_single -eq 0) {
    $album=Read-Host -Prompt "Name of the Album"
    $date=Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the release date of the album (in YYYY-MM-DD format, or type nothing if unknown)"
    $genre=Read-Host -Prompt "Genre of the Album" 
    $cover_art=Read-Host -Prompt "Select the audio/image file with the Cover Art (ex. MP3/M4A or JPG/PNG)"
    Get-ChildItem "*.mp3"
    $track_amount=Read-Host -Prompt "How many Tracks/Songs are in this Album"
    New-Item "$album [Generated].ps1" -ItemType File
    Write-Output -Path "$album [Generated].ps1" -Value 'This is a text test.'                           
}

# Singles
if ($album_or_single -eq 1) {
    $track_amount=Read-Host -Prompt "How many seperate Single's are there"  
}
```

Sorry for the bad formatting, and the (probably) improper use of brackets. The problem is that nothing ends up going into the generated file (it actually ends up generating). The last thing Powershell spits out is:

"-Path
In Sound Mind [Generated].ps1 (example sound-track)
-Value
This is a text test."

I'm sure I'm doing something very wrong, sorry if its a really easy fix. Thanks! (Also I'm doing this on Linux)

Revised sample (thanks Theo):

```
# Initialize
$TRACK_COUNTER=0

$artist=Read-Host -Prompt "Artist/Band Name"
$language=Read-Host -Prompt "Language (use ISO 639-2 codes)" 
$album_or_single=Read-Host -Prompt "Is this an Album/Sound-Track or a collection of Singles (0 for album/sound-track, 1 for single's)" 

# Album
if ($album_or_single -eq 0) {
    $album=Read-Host -Prompt "Name of the Album"
    $date=Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the release date of the album (in YYYY-MM-DD format, or type nothing if unknown)"
    $genre=Read-Host -Prompt "Genre of the Album" 
    $cover_art=Read-Host -Prompt "Select the audio/image file with the Cover Art (ex. MP3/M4A or JPG/PNG)"
    Get-ChildItem "*.mp3"
    $track_amount=Read-Host -Prompt "How many Tracks/Songs are in this Album"
    New-Item "$album [Generated].ps1" -ItemType File
    Add-Content -LiteralPath "$album [Generated].ps1" -Value 'This is a text test.'
                                
}

# Singles
if ($album_or_single -eq 1) {
        $track_amount=Read-Host -Prompt "How many seperate Single's are there"
        
}
```

Comment: Write-Output writes to console or pipeline. I think you're looking for Out-File to actually write to a file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: What is the meaning of the `Get-ChildItem "*.mp3"` line, when you do nothing with the resulting file list? Watch out for using square brackets in filenames. Cmdlets like `Get-ChildItem` need to use the `-LiteralPath` parameter for those instead of the (implied) `-Path` parameter

Comment: write-output has no -path or -value parameters.  You can verify that with tab completion.

Comment: @Theo I don't use it as a variable, and the script isn't complete yet. It was meant to list all the files in the shell so users could easily copy and paste the new line each time the script asks for the next file (such as asking to input the next .mp3 file name).

And the square brackets are breaking the script? I'm transferring from Batch script knowledge, and thought they would be okay haha. So '-LiteralPath' should make it ignore symbols in the filename?

Comment: Also here's a working Batch version of the script I'm currently trying to convert to PowerShell (to make it more cross-platform), this one works good: 

https://github.com/OrdinaryCarrot16/ffmpeg-conversion-scripts/blob/main/Amazon%20Music%20Conversion%20(FFmpeg)/Script%20Generator%20%5BSemi-Manual%5D.bat

Comment: @AlexanderJordan Would I be able to append new lines to the file with 'Write-Output' after the file is made?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm trying to do the equivalent of a Batch 'echo', and echo back some static lines with changing variables back to the file.